# How to get average rating of 5 for each post on a single query

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stored post's feedback comment and rating given by their customers. I just want to know how to query the average rating for each post divided by 5 in percentage.

So the formula will be like this. For example :

```
 (rate1 * customer) + (rate2 * customer)
----------------------------------------- * 100 / 5 = AVERAGE percentage within 5 stars rating
       total customer(per post)
```

So my query for now is like this :

```
SELECT 
    service_providers_post,
    rating,
    count(customer) as 'perrate_customers',
    t.perpost_customers
FROM serviceproviders_feedback
JOIN (SELECT 
        service_providers_post as 'postid',
        COUNT(customer) as 'perpost_customers'
    FROM serviceproviders_feedback
    GROUP BY service_providers_post) t
on t.postid = serviceproviders_feedback.service_providers_post
GROUP BY service_providers_post, rating
```

The output for the above query is like this :

[image: View query per rating]

The output that I want is to display average rating of each rate between 1 - 5 for each post.

So how to get the average for each post in a query?

Here a link as an example of my table

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/234dd9/6)

Comment: You should give a simple example of your database design and data related with the problem to let us understand it clearly. Check out the upper comment from @Strawberry

Comment: I have updated my post and make an example for sqlfiddle for others to try and solve :) @OnurBaştürk

Comment: It's very easy as shown in @Richmond's answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want only rating average :

```
SELECT 
    postid,
    avg(rating)
FROM ratings r
GROUP BY r.postid;
```

or a new column with the global average :

```
SELECT 
    postid,
    rating,
    count(customer) as 'perrate_customers',
    t.perpost_customers,
    t.perpost_rating_avg
FROM ratings r
JOIN (SELECT 
        postid as 'post_id',
        avg(rating) as 'perpost_rating_avg',
        COUNT(customer) as 'perpost_customers'
    FROM ratings
    GROUP BY postid) t
on t.post_id = r.postid
GROUP BY r.postid, r.rating
```

Comment: What if it is an average for 5 stars of rating for each post? So the output will group the average rating by postid. So the table will have 2 rows only which are postid 1 & 2.